# Hide an input value on the Front end While maintaining the value on the Back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I am trying to hide an input value. I want to use an input text type as sort of a password input field. I dont want the values to be displayed though. How to go about hiding the value after an insertion has been made? I would like the values to be hidden.

I have tried a few methods but no luck. I still need to access this in jquery/AJAX so I can pass it into SQL for password verification. Any help is most appreciated. Thanks

HTML

```
<input type=text id=num1 onclick="hideValue()">
```

Javascript

```
function hidevalue(){
   document.getElementById('num1').value.visibility="hidden";
}
```

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.password.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to tell it theat it is a password field.

```
<input type="password" id="num1">
```

Comment: thanks, but this will give me dots or '*'.. How do I get hidden values completely? No asteriks, just the value hidden??

Comment: In that case I think we are still in the dark.  If what you want is for the input to disappear after they click on it then, in addition to the above you use  `Arun's` javascript.  You execute it on click.

Answer (score 2):

Use field type as password to mask entry made by user.

To hide that field on click use the following in the function

```
document.getElementById('num1').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: this hides the input as well. Just trying for the value to be hidden

Comment: Then copy the value to a variable for later use, and set the value to "".